# CB Conditional field not letting me add extra AND rows

Tags: joomla-3.x, community-builder

I am trying to create a CB Conditional Field Show using an AND row, and it just won't let me.  I can add OR rows to my heart's content, but not an AND row. I click on the 'Add AND rows' and not a single thing happens.

Using Chrome, but have also tried on Microsoft Edge.  Other members of my team have tried on their computers and are having the same problem.

Joomla! 3.10.2
CB version 2.6.1